# ListView Selected Rows Colors Disappearing

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView activity that maintains a state array (3 choices, default=black, one click=green, second click=red) for all items in the list. The color of the list item/row changes based on user selection, so I can use the color of the item for later data labelling. Now everything works fine until I scroll the selected items off the screen and return them to the active view, when their custom color disappears. The state array still contains all the correct information, the custom colors just disappear. I was using an OnItemClickListener on the ListView to handle the color changes when an item was clicked, but I'm guessing that's not the best approach. What would be the best way to handle this?

Edit: Just to be clear, I'm allowing selection of multiple rows which have multiple colors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because you have an Adapter that is creating the row views for you. To be more efficient Adapters will reuse row views that are no longer visible on the screen. This reduces the number of views that have to be kept in memory. In order to get the colors to persist through scrolling them off the screen you'd have to find some way to store what color each item should be on and then have your adapter check for each item when it constructs the view and set the color accordingly.

Comment: Try to extend your adapter class, override the `getView` method and set the color for each row manually. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29

Comment: That's basically what I've been trying next, manually updating the state array every time the list view is clicked, then in the Adapter's getView() method, setting the appropriate background color. I guess I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but I'll see if that works. EDIT: Sorry Max, didn't see your comment. Yeah, I guess that's the way to go.

Comment: Got it working that way, thanks for the help guys. If anyone has a more elegant solution, feel free to post it.