# Solving the mystery of preserving selected states on views in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Not surprising I found myself looking at a tablet-optimized design one day that showed a pane with search results on the left side and a pane to display corresponding details on the right. The results on the left pane had a selected state to indicate which details were currently shown. What seemed to be a walk in the park ended up being a tiresome journey of trial and error. But finally I managed to get it working and I removed all irrelevant test-code only to discover it had stopped working straight away. I reintroduced the "irrelevant" part and surprisingly it worked as planned.

Client happy, designer happy, but not me, because I still don't understand why it works as it does.

1. I have a fragment that has a ListView with choiceMode set to **ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE**.
2. The adapter inflates custom views for each result and sets a drawable as background (happens in code)
3. The drawable is a selector wrapped in a RippleDrawable and has *checked* and *activated* states with a drawable for the selected state that needs to be preserved.
4. The custom view overrides *setSelected(boolean selected)* and dependent on the boolean adds or removes a view that has the selected state.

Now my problem is 3 & 4. Having the *checked* and *activated* states (step 3) ensures that *setSelected(true)* gets called when the view is tapped, but not immediately gets called again with *setSelected(false)* once the touchDown ends and thus the view I set in step 4 stays.

I had however expected I didn't need this custom view from step 4 as I thought it would use the drawable for the activated state from step 3. Removing the custom (thus unrelated to Android states system) view from step 4  has the effect that the state drawable from step 3 does show up, but only during `onPress` (touchDown/Hold) and... on the previous selected item!

**Item Background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:color="@color/light_gray">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_result_selector" />
</ripple>
```

**Selector Drawable (search_result_selector)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/white_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/white_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_result_highlighted_state" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_result_highlighted_state" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

**setSelected(selected)** on custom view used for items in `ListView`

```
@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    super.setSelected(selected);

    if (selected && selectedView == null) {
        selectedView = new View(getContext());
        selectedView.setBackground(Utils.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.action_bar_background));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(Utils.pxFromDp(getContext(), 3), getHeight());
        lp.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        addView(selectedView, lp);
    } else if (!selected && selectedView != null) {
        removeView(selectedView);
        selectedView = null;
    }
}
```

*selectedView* is a field I defined in my custom view class. I understand why it works, but I wonder why I need it as I expected the state drawable to be used correctly and preserve selection. The strange thing is when I remove that part, the `ListView` decides to do use the drawable, but on the previous selected view and only during touchDown. Now why would the presence of a custom implementation, not tied to any Android API influence the working of Android's view states? Apparently it is tied somehow, somewhere, but I fail to see where. Any pointers to the why behind this all would put my mind at ease. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
Apparently one of my conclusions was wrong. *setSelected(false)* was called, even with the states in the selector. Which makes sense perhaps if activated is the state that matters. I moved the code to an overriden method on setActivated, which does in fact show my custom view. That said the weirdness remains... the state drawable don't work as expected.

Comment: Is this a listview-adapter-view recycling issue as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340214/listview-selected-rows-colors-disappearing ?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be. The problem exists with just two items as well. No views are being recycled yet when the problem occurs.